# Can not get Request.azureMobile

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

i am trying to build Mobile App Service API with Node.js Backend
here is the Code that I implemented from Document of Microsoft but not working.
Here is My app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    azureMobileApps = require('azure-mobile-apps');


var app = express();
var loginApi = require('./api/login');
var mobile = azureMobileApps();


var mobileApp = azureMobileApps({
    // Explicitly enable the Azure Mobile Apps home page
    homePage: true,
    // Explicitly enable swagger support. UI support is enabled by
    // installing the swagger-ui npm module.
    swagger: true
});

mobileApp.tables.import('./tables');

 mobileApp.api.import('./api');

app.use('/login', loginApi(mobile.configuration));

mobileApp.tables.initialize()
    .then(function () {
        app.use(mobileApp);  
        app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);  
    });
```

Here is My  Login api

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');


module.exports = function (configuration) {
    var router = express.Router();

    router.get('/',(req, res, next) => {
        console.log(req.azureMobile);
    });

    return router;
};
```

and the error is req.azureMobile is undefined
i don't know how to make this working, and i just try to test from browser just insert the url get method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already fixed this problem, i need to add api in Easy api

Comment: Can you show how to do this, ideally without having to put your JS files in magic folders?